# Unexpected symbol in bmm file for Microblaze

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, microblaze

I am trying to get to grips with a simple Microblaze project, and have followed a [tutorial](http://ibelimb.com/2014/03/30/generating-a-microblaze-soft-processor-with-ise-webpack-14-dot-7/) I have found closely. I can synthesize the design in ISE successfully, but when I try and implement the design I get the following error:

> ERROR::11 - Unexpected symbol 'MICROBLAZE', 'ADDRESS_MAP name' expected.
>      Line #1, File "ipcore_dir/microblaze.bmm".
>   ERROR:NgdBuild:989 - Failed to process BMM information ipcore_dir/microblaze.bmm

The file microblaze.bmm is generated by the microblaze core generator so I've not edited the contents.

The .bmm file generated with the microblaze core is:

```
ADDRESS_MAP microblaze MICROBLAZE-LE 100
  ADDRESS_SPACE lmb_bram COMBINED [0x00000000:0x00001fff]
   ADDRESS_RANGE RAMB16
    BUS_BLOCK
    mcs_0/U0/lmb_bram_I/RAM_Inst/Using_B16_S9.The_BRAMs[0].RAMB16_S9_1 [31:24] INPUT = microblaze.lmb_bram_0.mem;
    mcs_0/U0/lmb_bram_I/RAM_Inst/Using_B16_S9.The_BRAMs[1].RAMB16_S9_1 [23:16] INPUT = microblaze.lmb_bram_1.mem;
    mcs_0/U0/lmb_bram_I/RAM_Inst/Using_B16_S9.The_BRAMs[2].RAMB16_S9_1 [15:8] INPUT = microblaze.lmb_bram_2.mem;
    mcs_0/U0/lmb_bram_I/RAM_Inst/Using_B16_S9.The_BRAMs[3].RAMB16_S9_1 [7:0] INPUT = microblaze.lmb_bram_3.mem;
  END_BUS_BLOCK;
 END_ADDRESS_RANGE;
 END_ADDRESS_SPACE;
 END_ADDRESS_MAP;
```

And the microblaze is instantiated with this vhdl code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity microblaze_top is
PORT (
   Clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
   Reset : IN STD_LOGIC;
   UART_Rx : IN STD_LOGIC;
   UART_Tx : OUT STD_LOGIC;
   GPO1 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0)    
 );
end microblaze_top;

architecture Behavioral of microblaze_top is
COMPONENT microblaze
PORT (
   Clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
   Reset : IN STD_LOGIC;
   UART_Rx : IN STD_LOGIC;
   UART_Tx : OUT STD_LOGIC;
   FIT1_Interrupt : OUT STD_LOGIC;
   FIT1_Toggle : OUT STD_LOGIC;
   GPO1 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
   INTC_IRQ : OUT STD_LOGIC
);
END COMPONENT;
begin
  mcs_0 : microblaze
  PORT MAP (
    Clk => Clk,
    Reset => Reset,
    UART_Rx => UART_Rx,
    UART_Tx => UART_Tx,
    GPO1 => GPO1
  );
  end Behavioral;
```

I have run this command in the TCL console to include the microblaze in the synthesis.

> source ipcore_dir/microblaze_mcs_setup.tcl

I have spent ages trawling various tutorials and I cannot fathom what the problem is. Can someone please give me a hint as to what is going wrong.

I don't seem to be able to find a way to contact the author of the tutorial.

I'm using ISE14.7 running in a virtual appliance.

(Edit - added the following aditional info)

I have taken a look in the console tab which appears to give some more info, compared to the Errors tab:

> ERROR::37 - Illegal file or path name symbol 'MICROBLAZE'.
>      Line #5, File "ipcore_dir/microblaze.bmm".
>           mcs_0/U0/lmb_bram_I/RAM_Inst/Using_B16_S9.The_BRAMs[0].RAMB16_S9_1 [31:24] INPUT = microblaze.lmb_bram_0.mem;

Looking closely ISE is not happy about *microblaze.lmb_bram_0.mem;* I'm not clear why though.

Below is a snapshot of the project Hierarchy:

[image: project Hierarchy]

And this is the MicroBlaze setup

[image: MicroBlaze Setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this page](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Archived-ISE-issues-Archived/ERROR-NgdBuild-927-Failed-to-process-BMM-file-edkBmmFile-bmm/td-p/12558), and the suggestion is that the naming in the bmm file might not be matching what you have in your design hierarchy. Can you confirm that? Since you have a name related error. `microblaze` might be invalid.

As you have updated your answer, it is visible that the hierarchical design name for it is in fact `msc_0`. Updating your bmm file with the correct naming would resolve the issue!